# springframework.test not importing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to create a project with Spring boot and Maven but I keep getting "cannot be resolved" errors when I try to import the test part.
I have test in my pom.xml but I keep getting errors. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!
test class

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FinalProjV1ApplicationTests {
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I removed some of the code as it didn't seem important and there was already too much code with this question

Comment: Is your `FinalProjV1ApplicationTests`  in `src/test/java`? Or in `src/main/java`? Also you included `spring-boot-starter-test` twice. Another tip instead of `hibernate-validator` use `spring-boot-starter-validation`  instead.

Comment: Try to add more info to questions. Like basic project structure, where are your files located?

Comment: @darren I'm sure the main and test are seperate folders *BUT* that wasn't my question. The question was in which of those is your `FinalProjV1ApplicationTests` located.

Comment: Also please include your full `pom.xml` instead of only this snippet.

Answer (score -1):

`SpringRunner` is a part of `JUnit4` (as indicated in the import) and `JUnit4` is not included in your dependencies.

Your version of `Spring Boot` is probably using `JUnit5`.

Comment: This is for a college project and I'm using the basic versions that were included in the project description. How can I check what version of JUnit Spring Boot is running on?

Comment: @M. Deinum     Test and Main are in two separate folders.

Comment: In the `pom.xml` look for `spring-boot-starter-parent` and find out its version. A quick search would help you in finding which JUnit is available in that version. Also, you can just add `JUnit4` as a dependency and be done with it, although not recommended.

Comment: The default for Spring is JUnit4 and is part of `spring-boot-starter-test`.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are wrong, please check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.2.6.RELEASE and you would see that there is no `JUnit`, just `Jupiter` (aka `JUnit5`).

Comment: Let me correct that, it is junit5 is included but with the default vintage runner, and thus pointing to JUnit4. Also `SpringRunner` is part of Spring Test **NOT** JUnit4. So unless you are excluding the vintage engine it still is using JUnit4 by default.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are not entirely correct again. According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringRunner.html , this is an alias for `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html` which is a part of `JUnit4`. Also it mentions that `This class requires JUnit 4.12 or higher`. Anyway, you think this is not a problem with spring boot version?

Comment: No it isn't. The `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is also part of Spring and NOT JUnit, it **requires** JUnit4 which is something else as being part of JUnit4! JUnit doesn't have anything framework specific only for its self. Again the point is that by default JUnit4 and its dependencies are included and your answer isn't going to help.